# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name xxx available as request attribute

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

"Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'loginCommand' available as request attribute"

I keep getting this Binding result error and nothing I've tried seems to be making it stop. I've seen other posts for this question, but none of them seem to fix whatever issue I'm having.

This is the first controller of my new project and I had some issues getting the xml squared away. I think that's all fixed, but if nothing looks off I supposed the problem could be there. The weird thing is that all this code is almost straight copied from another project I have and it works just fine.

Also I'm running on glassfish if that matters at all. Thanks in advance!

edit: The webpage is /morencore/login.jsp. I tried going to login.html assuming that would bring it up, but it only seems to work when I go to login.jsp. I believe I tried changing my controller to map to the jsp instead, but that did not work.

here is my login.jsp page:

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="loginCommand">

    <form:errors cssClass="error" element="p" />

    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Username:</td>
            <td><form:input path="userName" /> <form:errors path="userName" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Password:</td>
            <td><form:password path="password" /> <form:errors path="password" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" disabled="disabled"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form:form>
```

and here is my controller:

```
@Controller
@ControllerAdvice
@RequestMapping("/login.html")
public class LoginController {

    protected final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    protected LoginValidator loginValidator;

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
    protected String initializeForm(@ModelAttribute("loginCommand")LoginCommand loginCommand,
                                    BindingResult result,
                                    ModelMap model)
    {
        logger.info("INITIALIZING LOGIN FORM");
        model.addAttribute("loginCommand", new LoginCommand());
        return "login";
    }

    @InitBinder("loginCommand")
    protected void initBinder(ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception
    {
        binder.addValidators(loginValidator);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    protected String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("loginCommand")LoginCommand loginCommand,
                              BindingResult result,
                              HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
    {
        logger.info("validating login input");
        loginValidator.validate(loginCommand, result);

        if (result.hasErrors())
        {
            result.reject("login.failure");
            return "login";
        }
        UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
        User user = userDao.by_name(loginCommand.getUserName());
        if (user == null
                || !user.getName().equals(loginCommand.getUserName())
                || !user.getPassword().equals(loginCommand.getPassword()))
        {
            result.reject("login.failure");
            return "login";
        }
        return "redirect:main.html";
    }
}
```

Here is my LoginCommand class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class LoginCommand
{
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    /** blah blah blah getters and setters*/
}
```

Here is the full stack trace as requested:

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'loginCommand' available as request attribute
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'loginCommand' available as request attribute
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:142)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
        at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_form_input_0(login_jsp.java:233)
        at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:126)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
```

Comment: Please explain your flow. Which URL do you originally hit to see the form? Do you submit the form? Does it successfully redirect? Show us a full stacktrace.

Comment: I updated my post with the stack trace and flow based on your comments.

Comment: Well there's your problem. If you're going through the page (which I assume is public, it shouldn't be), Spring MVC isn't involved at all, and does not add the model attribute you expect.

Comment: What do you mean by going through the page?

Comment: The JSP is rendered outside the context of Spring MVC. Your controller handler method is never executed to render that JSP, it's all done directly by your Servlet container.

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, it seems like your mappings need to be modified.  Here is what I would try.  There are a lot of adjustments so no guarantees on whether it will work completely, but it should get you in the right direction.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    protected final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());  //look at SLF4J instead.  Then you're not tied to a specific logger and you use a facade.

    @Autowired //may want to use constructor wiring instead on these
    private LoginValidator loginValidator;

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao; //this should be wired and not simply instantiated - Spring won't know about it otherwise

    @Autowired
    private LoginValidator loginValidator;

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String initializeForm(Model model) {
        logger.info("INITIALIZING LOGIN FORM");
        model.addAttribute("loginCommand", new LoginCommand());
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/loginPost")
    public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("loginCommand") LoginCommand loginCommand,
                            BindingResult result) throws Exception {

        logger.info("validating login input");
        loginValidator.validate(loginCommand, result);

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            result.reject("login.failure");
            return "login";
        }

        User user = userDao.by_name(loginCommand.getUserName());
        if (user == null
                || !user.getName().equals(loginCommand.getUserName())
                || !user.getPassword().equals(loginCommand.getPassword())) { //you should really refactor this and move it outside of your controller.  Just keep routing code in your controller, not logic

            result.reject("login.failure");
            return "login";
        }
        return "main"; //you should return just "main" or redirect:/main depending on what you're trying to do - you want the JSP to be processed.  Leaving off the extension allows you to change frameworks without changing the server-side code and allows the page to be compiled.  You could switch to Thymeleaf, for example, and not touch any of this code.
    }
}
```

Add an action to your form:

```
<form:errors cssClass="error" element="p" />

<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Username:</td>
        <td><form:input path="userName" /> <form:errors path="userName" cssClass="error" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Password:</td>
        <td><form:password path="password" /> <form:errors path="password" cssClass="error" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Log In"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For the next developer reading your code, I'd rename `LoginCommand` to something closer to what it actually is - like `UserDetailsAdapter` or something along those lines.  I am assuming that `LoginCommand` will implement `UserDetails` from Spring Security if you're using that.

You may also want to consider updating your `UserDao` to have the method called `findOneByUsername` instead of `by_name`.  The naming convention can help you later when you use Spring Repositories.

Lastly, look at [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) for your beans.  It'll save you lots of headaches.